# How to trigger subcomponents in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to use the **lazy loading** subcomponents as shown in

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/sub-components-lazy

I am wondering how I can trigger the subcomponents after a change in the subcomponent.

for example

parent A

- sub A1
- sub A2

I want to re-render the sub-components list by triggering the API call (Lazy loading)

I don't want to use the [image]

hand button which is shown in the table.

e.g if the user creates a new record (sub component) I want to trigger the subcomponent list re render programatically